# how to send an hexadecimal from python to the UART?

Tags: python, c, uart

I need to understand how to send a message in hexadecimal format from UART for example: 
msg='99' +'70b4c55ad8cdb7806a7b043069c4e0d8'

'99'is to distinct the start of message and the rest is the data. 
As 
    import serial
    import time

```
#serial port   
ser = serial.Serial(
                    port='COM4',\
                    baudrate=230400,\
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                    timeout=0)  

   msg=b'\x99\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8\xcd\xb7\x80\x6a\x7b\x04\x30\x69\xc4\xe0\xd8'
   ser.write(msg)
   time.sleep(0.4)

while True:
  print(ser.read(30))
ser.close()             # close ports
```

But i don't unerstand th error:

```
 msg= b'\x99\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8\xcd\xb7\x80\x6a\x7b\x04\x30\x69\xc4\xe0\xd8'
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I need then to compare by using c langage, to compare the first received byte 99 with 0x99.

```
int lenght = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read((void*)buffer,34 );

        if (lenght<34)
        {
          if buffer [0]='0x99'
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You realize that 99 is a valid hex number, right? That makes it a bad start marker.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I start using hexadecimal, uart and c very recently, I am open to all tip of advice and suggestion

Comment: You've got a great answer about using a bytes object but if you have a hex string to start off with, you can `binascii.unhexlify('99' +'70b4c55ad8cdb7806a7b043069c4e0d8')`.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer, however I want to send an hexadecimal bytes, in order to make easy to use by file in c

Comment: @MarkRansom every "hex number" is "valid". The data is raw bytes, so there is no means of out-of-band signalling.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it looked from the text of the question that they were sending ASCII characters as a hex string to be decoded, but reading closer today I can see they're really sending binary.  In that case indeed every value is valid.  You need a much more robust protocol in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems like you are loading to `buf` but using `buffer` in your c code.
2. You are reading 34 bytes to the buffer, then checking if the length is less than 34. Shouldn't work well. And judging by your example, it should be 17.
3. Encode will not convert `msg` to hex string. It will treat every character as a char, i.e. `'0'` is `48`, `'1'` is `49` etc

Create bytes object using

```
msg = b'\x99\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8\xcd\xb7\x80\x6a\x7b\x04\x30\x69\xc4\xe0\xd8'
ser.write(msg)
```

Comment: It gives me an error:    msg = b'\x99\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8\xcd\xb7\x80\x6a\x7b\x04\x30\x69\xc4\xe0\xd8'
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: check your indentation. this is probably inside a function, so it should be proceeded by 4 spaces or tab.

Comment: `b'...'` creates a byte object of its contents, like `.encode()`. but using this way, you can initialize with hex values.

Comment: Thank you @Uriel, that is all my python file : import serial
import time '#serial port   
ser = serial.Serial(
     port='COM4',\
     baudrate=230400,\
     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
     timeout=0) 

   msg= b'\x99\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8\xcd\xb7\x80\x6a\x7b\x04\x30\x69\xc4\xe0\xd8'
   ser.write(msg)
   time.sleep(0.4)

while True:
  print(ser.read(30))
ser.close()             # close ports'
   
But i don't unerstand th error  msg= b'\x99\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8....xd8'IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: I cannot see your indentation in the one line code, please update it in the question (copy the code as it looks and edit the question)

Comment: `msg=` and the two following lines have 4 additional spaces before them. Delete this spaces.

Comment: Thanks I did that , but the message is displayed by this way:  Öp┤┼ZÏ═ÀÇj{0i─ÓÏ

Comment: You are reading bytes stream from the serial. These characters are the ASCII representation of this bytes stream.

Comment: I am very gratefuk for your helo really, could you please tell me how to hae the best representation, because when I try to display the receiver value by using     printf("test %s\n", buffer);                                                             test= Öp┤┼ZÏ═ÀÇj{0i─ÓÏ}ñç▄

Comment: I am very grateful for your help really, could you please tell me how to hae the best representation, because when I try to display the receiver value by using printf("test %s\n", buffer); test= Öp┤┼ZÏ═ÀÇj{0i─ÓÏ}ñç▄ –

Comment: I cannot fully recreate your code, but I suggest you try `printf("test %x\n", buffer);` that should format it as hexadecimal rep.